# Difference between CreateRequestClient and CreatePublishRequestClient

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, masstransit

In a Request Response pattern using MassTransit with RabbitMQ, I'm trying to create a request client. But when doing some research on the internet i saw two possibilities:

CreateRequestClient and CreatePublishRequestClient

Does someone know what's the difference between those two and when to use them?

see below for the methods:

```
  public static class RequestClientExtensions
  {
    public static IRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse> CreateRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse>(this IBus bus, Uri address, TimeSpan timeout, TimeSpan? ttl = null, Action<SendContext<TRequest>> callback = null) where TRequest : class where TResponse : class
    {
      return (IRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse>) new MessageRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse>(bus, address, timeout, ttl, callback);
    }

    public static IRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse> CreatePublishRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse>(this IBus bus, TimeSpan timeout, TimeSpan? ttl = null, Action<SendContext<TRequest>> callback = null) where TRequest : class where TResponse : class
    {
      return (IRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse>) new PublishRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse>(bus, timeout, ttl, callback);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the set of arguments explain the difference. This is the same difference as we have between `Send` and `Publish`. `Publish` uses fan-out exchange and `Send` delivers to a specific exchange only.

Normal `RequestClient` will do `Send` under the hood and needs the receiver address.

`PublishRequestClient` does not need any address since it will just publish the message and hope that someone will reply to it.

If you want to know more about `Send` vs `Publish` difference, you can check this [blog post](https://www.maldworth.com/2015/10/27/masstransit-send-vs-publish/).

Comment: Thank you for this amazing reply. Do you also know what I have to pass as the address? In some examples I see rabbitmq://localhost/test/request_service. But when I try this, the url is not recognized. It is also never explained in the examples.

Comment: Some more explanation: i want to know where I can configure the '/test/request_service' part of the url. There is not much documentation about this on the internet.

Comment: If you have two services and you ask from one to another, the address in the request client is the address of the service that should process your request. It is like `new Uri("rabbitmq://servicebushost/second_service_queue")`

Comment: Shouldn't '/second_service_queue' be the exchange name instead of the queue name or am I wrong? I tried using the method CreateRequestClient. I passed the following address: rabbitmq://localhost/<exchange name> and it worked! (in my case, exchange name is the same as the queue name anyway, but I wanted to be sure).

Comment: No, the service Uri is a queue name of the receiving endpoint where you send the request to. Well, in RabbitMQ you cannot send to a queue so yes, you are sending to an exchange, but the service exchange, which is the same as the queue name. So if you have `cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://servicebus/vhost"))` and `cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "second_service", ...)`, the request client should use `rabbitmq://servicebus/vhost/second_service`